# pass data from a table view Controller to View Controller using data stored in core data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I'm a little newbie and I have a doubt, I have a `TableViewController` and another `ViewController` that I have as a `detailViewController`, what I try to do is that when a cell is selected in the `tableview`, it presents the corresponding data stored in core data for that cell in the `detailViewcontroller`.

This is the file that controls the `tableViewcontroller` :

```
import UIKit

class CostumerTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var costumerArray:[Costumer] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.fetchData()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return costumerArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let name = costumerArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = name.costumerName!
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            let costumerDelete = costumerArray[indexPath.row]
            context.delete(costumerDelete)
            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
            do {
                costumerArray = try context.fetch(Costumer.fetchRequest())
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let DvC = Storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "costumerDetailViewController") as! costumerDetailViewController
        let n = costumerArray[indexPath.row]
        let Cn = n.costumerName!
        DvC.getCostumerName = Cn
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DvC, animated: true)
    }

    func fetchData() {
        // se crea el context
        let  context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        do {  // se hace el request del array
            costumerArray = try context.fetch(Costumer.fetchRequest())
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

In the compilation does not give me any problem, some everything goes well the problem is that it does not present anything in the detail `viewController` label that in this case I try to send the data from this code.

This is the `detailViewController` code :

```
import UIKit

class costumerDetailViewController: UIViewController {
    var getCostumerName = String()

    @IBOutlet weak var labelName: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        labelName.text! = getCostumerName
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you creating String object "var getCostumerName = String()" in second controller? Just declare it as a type "var getCostumerName:String?"  .

Answer (score 1):

First Check `Cn` has value or "" on this line.

```
let Cn = n.costumerName
```

Change your code in class `costumerDetailViewController` for declare `getCostumerName`

```
var getCostumerName = "" //for avoid crash. if value goes nil.
```

Use `Print()` in viewDidLoad and debug it.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: when I change `var getCostumerName:String?` because Xcode say add ! in this line `labelName.text! = getCostumerName!` I get this error Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Did you print `DvC.getCostumerName`, it has value or nil?

Comment: any value I don't know why , I try print in console to se the value and don't show any value